# Swapping elements in python

Tags: python

```
def jump_left(markers, row, column):
    """
    Returns the grid that results after the marker at (row, column) jumps left
    @type markers: list[list[str]]
    @type row: int
    @type column: int
    @rtype: list[GridPegSolitairePuzzle]
    >>> grid = [["*", "*", "*", "*", "*"]]
    >>> grid.append(["*", "*", "*", "*", "*"])
    >>> grid.append(["*", "*", "*", "*", "*"])
    >>> grid.append(["*", "*", ".", "*", "*"])
    >>> grid.append(["*", "*", "*", "*", "*"])
    >>> gpsp1 = GridPegSolitairePuzzle(grid, {"*", ".", "#"})
    >>> L1 = jump_left(gpsp1._marker, 3, 4)
    >>> grid[3][2] = "*"
    >>> grid[3][3] = "."
    >>> grid[3][4] = "."
    >>> L2 = [GridPegSolitairePuzzle(grid, {"*", ".", "#"})]
    >>> L1 == L2
    True
    """
    # Checking bounds and whether the right pieces are in the positions needed
    if (column - 2) >= 0 and (markers[row][column - 2] == ".") and\
                             (markers[row][column - 1] == "*"):

        # Each row must be copied individually (since they are all lists)
        m_copy = []
        for i in range(len(markers)):
            m_copy.append(markers[i].copy())

        new_grid = GridPegSolitairePuzzle(m_copy, {"*", ".", "#"})

        # Performs the jump
        new_grid._marker[row][column] = "."
        new_grid._marker[row][column - 1] = "."
        new_grid._marker[row][column - 2] = "*"

        return [new_grid]

    else:
        return []
```

My program is supposed to move the peg denoted by '*' and by jumping to the empty spot ('.') and removing the peg between.

So for the above docstring: r1 would become

```
 ["*", "*", ".", "."]
```

My code works for the shown docstring but if  `r1 = ["*", "*", ".", "*"]` and `r3  = ["*", ".", "*", "*"]`.

It should swap the r3 elements, but it doesn't work (I know im not iterating through each empty position, but i cant find a way to do it)

Also is there a better way to do in the index out of range. Im doing try and except block because if the empty position is in column 3, it will give me index out of range since im looking for the pegs beside it

Comment: Can you describe what you want to do (the rule of your game) in natural language? It is hard to understand your destination with your code only.

Comment: @charlee its a peg solitaire, the function just moves the peg to the left

Comment: what did you mean by "if  r1 = ["*", "*", ".", "*"] and r3  = ["*", ".", "*", "*"]. It should swap the r3 elements, but it doesn't work"? What is it supposed to be?

Comment: for r1 it shouldn't swap because to the right of the empty position there is only one peg, but for r3 it should swap since there are two pegs to the right of the empty position

Comment: got you. so your confusion is how to deal with index out of range. Answer will come in minutes.

Comment: @charlee will ur solution also help with the r3 and r1 thing i explained lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make the loop range smaller to avoid index out of range.
Because you cannot jump any peg into the two right-most places, there's no need to check those. In this way you don't need to worry about out of range.

```
class Sol(object):


    def __init__(self):
        self._marker = [
            ['.', '*', '*', '*'],
            ['*', '.', '*', '*'],
            ['*', '*', '.', '*'],
            ['*', '*', '*', '.'],
        ]

    def move_left(self):
        for row in self._marker:
            for idx, cell in enumerate(row):
                # No need to check the right-most and 2nd right-most cells
                # because you can't move left to those cells.
                if idx >= len(row) - 2:
                    break

                if cell == '.' and row[idx + 1] == '*' and row[idx + 2] == '*':
                    row[idx] = '*'
                    row[idx + 1] = '.'
                    row[idx + 2] = '.'

    def print_board(self):
        for row in self._marker:
            print(' '.join(row))



sol = Sol()
sol.move_left()
sol.print_board()
```

Result:

```
* . . *
* * . .
* * . *
* * * .
```

Comment: is there a way to do this without using enumerate

Comment: @TheGamer you can use your `range(len(self._marker))` as well. `enumerate` is just a convenient way of getting both index and element in one call.

Comment: so would i do for idx, cell in range(len(self._marker))

Comment: `for r in range(len(self._marker)): row = self._marker[r]` is equivalent to `for r, row in enumerate(self._marker)`

Answer (score 0):

Currently, your code will only jump to the left.  It also will not jump vertically.

You need to also be able to do self.marker[r][c - {1,2}] and self.marker[r +- {1,2}[c] transformations.

Realistically, the "jump" operation should likely be its own function, in order to simplify this code a bit.

Comment: Jordan i have different function for vertical

Comment: the function move is actually left

Comment: That's fine I guess (I probably would recommend not doing that), but this still cannot jump to the left.

Comment: well my code looks at the right side of the empty peg and then switches it

Comment: so i do [r][c+{1,2}]

Comment: Currently, you're editing [r][c+0], [r][c+1] and r[c+2], what I meant was, you also need to be able to edit [r][c-0], [r][c-1] and r[c-2]

Comment: sorry to bother u again but the thing ur telling me do i make it in the if statement

Comment: If you really want to keep the code the way it is, you will need a second if statement.